# Design issue while using ACF form in frontend

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i have a different admin template where i want to use ACF form for custom post type.i am getting the result correctly but the problem is header and footer appearing twice and design are not appearing correctly like in wp-admin e:g 1 button are looking like label and datepicker not popup correctly.here i am sharing two screenshot to show how the design appearing different from actual design.

[image: wp-admin screenshot]

[image: Front end screenshot]

This is what i have tried

```
<?php
acf_form_head();
get_header();
?>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php
        acf_form( array(
            'post_id' => 90,
            'field_groups' => array( 43 ),
            'submit_value' => 'Submit',
        ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: what is the code inside your acf_form_head(), get_header(), and get_footer() ?

Comment: in the index.php file i have only the above code nothing else and i get the form as a result which i already share above

Answer (score 0):

In the Documentation for [ACF Form](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/), the `acf_form()` function is called inside the loop. Maybe that is the issue for some reason? can you try:

```
<?php 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
acf_form( array(
  'post_id' => 90,
  'field_groups' => array( 43 ),
  'submit_value' => 'Submit',
) );
endwhile; 
?>
```

See if that works...